# SQL Connect error in Python(Windows): severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed

Tags: python, sql, database, azure

Not able to connect to Azure DB. I get the following error while connecting  via Python.

I'm able to connect to my usual SQL environment

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql
connPDW = pymssql.connect(host=r'dwprd01.database.windows.net', user=r'internal\admaaron',password='',database='')
connPDW.autocommit(True)
cursor = connPDW.cursor() 

conn.autocommit(True)
cursor = conn.cursor()


sql = """

select Top (10) * from TableName

"""
cursor.execute(sql);
```

Run without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just according to your code, there is an obvious issue of connecting Azure SQL Database by `pymssql` package in Python which use the incorrect user format and lack of the values of `password` and `database` parameters.

Please follow the offical document [`Step 3: Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pymssql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pymssql?view=sql-server-2017) carefully to change your code correctly.

If you have an instance of Azure SQL Database with the connection string of ODBC, such as `Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<your hostname>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<your database name>;Uid=<username>@<host>;Pwd=<your_password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;` show in the `Connection strings` tab of your SQL Database on Azure portal.

[image]

Then, your code should be like below

```
hostname = '<your hostname>'
server = f"{hostname}.database.windows.net"
username = '<your username>'
user = f"{username}@{hostname}"
password = '<your password>'
database = '<your database name>'

import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server=server, user=user, password=password, database=database)
```

Meanwhile, just additional note for the version of Azure SQL Database and MS SQL Server are `2008+` like the latest Azure SQL Database, you should use the ODBC Driver connection string which be started with `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};`, not `13` show in the connection string of Azure portal if using ODBC driver for Python with `pyodbc`, please refer to the offical document [`Step 3: Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pyodbc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017).